# Firestore check if the logged in user verified his email

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, angularfire2

So I have a collection in firestore that should only be accessible to logged in and verified users.

This is how I secure it:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function emailVerified() {
      return request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider != 'password'
            || request.auth.token.email_verified == true;
    }

    match /users/{userId} {
      allow get: if request.auth.uid != null && emailVerified();
    }
  }
}
```

Using the rules emulator this works as expected:

| Auth Provider | Email **not** verified | Email verified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Google | ✔️ | ✔️ (but not really needed, since we don't send verifications for providers other than email) |
| Email | ❌ | ✔️ |

But using the frontend this happens:

| Auth Provider | Email **not** verified | Email verified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Google | ✔️ | ✔️ |
| Email | ❌ | ❌ → fails with a `Missing or insufficient permissions` |

Here are the relevant snippets from my frontend code:

```
// currentAuthUserObs() is the current auth user from firebase  (that part works)
// isEmailVerified() is described further down (works too)
// afStorage is AngularFire2's Firestore module

// 'HERE' and 'HERE2' are both printed, so that works as expected. The problem really is the query

this.auth.currentAuthUserObs().subscribe(async (authUser) => {
    console.log('HERE');
    if (authUser != null && await this.auth.emailAuth.isEmailVerified()) {
        console.log('HERE2');
        this.afStorage.doc(`${FirestoreCollections.USERS}/${authUser.uid}`).valueChanges()
            .subscribe(user => {
                console.log(user);
            });
    }
});


// In my case isEmailVerified gets called before and refreshes the currentUser, so it is ok to not call it with `refresh = true` in the subscription above.
public async isEmailVerified(refresh = false): Promise<boolean> {
    if (refresh) {
        await firebase.auth().currentUser.reload();
    }

    const isEmail = () => firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData.some(provider => provider.providerId == 'password');
    return isEmail() ? firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified : true;
}
```

Does someone have any clue what the problem could possibly be?

Comment: If it works in the emulator and not in the front end, then either the rules deployed don't match your test set, or the authenticated user's token does not contain the fields expected. I'm pretty sure you need to reload the auth id token with boolean true (not the currentUser) to get this to update.

Comment: Even if I refresh the page and everything, it dows not work. also checking for `emailVerified` in the frontend returns `true` so it **is** correct in the frontend. Furthermore what the frontend thinks about the user should not be relevant to the backend anyways. But I will try to reload the token instead. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Just tested it. You are completely right, the token did the trick! Can you phrase it as an answer, so that I can accept it please? @Kato

Comment: Instead, you should post a quick not on what turned out to be the root cause and we can upvote and accept that : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the user @Kato pointed out, the ID token of the user needs a refresh. You can do that using `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)` - which looks like that in my example:

```
public async isEmailVerified(refresh = false): Promise<boolean> {
    if (refresh) {
        await firebase.auth().currentUser.reload();
        await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true); // <-- here
    }

    const isEmail = () => firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData.some(provider => provider.providerId == 'password');
    return isEmail() ? firebase.auth().currentUser.emailVerified : true;
}
```